# cbind a vector of different length to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have a dataframe consisting of two samples. Only one sample has answered a questionnaire about state anxiety. 
For this case, I have calculated a vector for somatic state anxiety with the following function "rowSums":

```
som_lp <- rowSums(sample1[,c(1, 7, 8, 10 )+108], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now I would like to add this to my existing dataframe "data", but the function "cbind" doesn't work here, because of the different lengths (dataframe 88, som_lp 59).

```
data <- cbind(data, som_lp)
```

Can anyone help me and is there another option to calculate "som_lp" to avoid the different lengths?

Comment: How is the data frame supposed to know to which cases the anxiety scores belong? One method to make that explicit would be to first do `data$som_lp <- NA` (creating an empty column) and then something like `data$som_lp[ind] <- som_lp`, where `ind` is your index vector (say `ind <- 1:length(som_lp)`). Otherwise the assignment will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(data, som_lp, fill = NA)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. But how do I calculate descriptive statistics (mean, sd, median, etc.) for this vector?

Comment: @C.Meadow You can use `summary(som_lp)`

Comment: Just make sure to be cautious when using `cbind.fill`. See how it fills up the data.frame:
`sample1 <- data.frame((seq(10))); sample2 <- seq(7); cbind.fill(sample1,sample2)`. I do not think this is how you want it to work.

Comment: @Therkel You can add the option `fill= NA`

Comment: Unfortunately the rowr package is no longer available on CRAN