# R shiny deployment - replacing rowr cbind.fill

Tags: r, heroku, shiny

I am deploying a Shiny App on Heroku.

However the buildpack does not support rowr as the version of R is not compatible with this package.

How can I replace rowr::cbind.fill with base R or dplyr functions ?

I tried to see what was in the function, but it is not clear to me:

```
function (..., fill = NULL) 
{
    inputs <- list(...)
    inputs <- lapply(inputs, vert)
    maxlength <- max(unlist(lapply(inputs, len)))
    bufferedInputs <- lapply(inputs, buffer, length.out = maxlength, 
        fill, preserveClass = FALSE)
    return(Reduce(cbind.data.frame, bufferedInputs))
}
```

Another way of asking this question is is there a solution to the following question in dplyr, I need fill = NA ?

[cbind a vector of different length to a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720373/cbind-a-vector-of-different-length-to-a-dataframe)

Comment: If you want a `cbind` for columns with different lengths, you could first append the shorter columns with `NA`s so that they have the same length and then use `cbind`

Comment: yes but I need to redimension the one that is shorter and I don't know which one it is and then add an NA to the top or bottom but how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to detect the number of missing elements in every column, append it with `NA`s and bind it together. I assume that the columns are stored in a list:

```
# test data
test_data <- list(c1 = rep(1, 5),
                  c2 = rep(2, 7),
                  c3 = rep(3, 4))

# find the longest column
longest_column <- max(unlist(lapply(test_data, length)))

# calculate how many NAs need to be added
number_append <- lapply(test_data, function(x) longest_column - length(x))

# append the columns
data_appended <- lapply(seq_len(length(test_data)), function(i) {
  c(test_data[[i]], rep(NA, number_append[[i]]))
})

# combine the columns
data_combined <- do.call("cbind", data_appended)
```